# Inserting rules in CSS by the user

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to enable users to change the style of the site by selecting properties from a drop down. When an element is selected, a function would insert the rule into the CSS. I thought the JavaScript code for that is something like:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[];
sheet.insertRule(rule,index);
```

But I can't get it to work. First the function should check if there is already a value for the specific stylerule. If so, it should remove the rule before adding the new one. So if it is trying to add a fontsize of 16 on index 1 and there is already a fontsize it should overwrite it, otherwise it should just add the rule...

Comment: Crappy English? No, this is better than 90% of the questions submitted to Stack Overflow. You have nothing to be ashamed of (although improvement is always possible). Keep it up.

Comment: why don't you just toggle classes? instead of injecting "dynamic" css into your site? Even the fontsize example can be implemented by setting the fontsize on the `body` tag and using relative fontsizes for the nodes that should be styled.

Answer (score 0):

`document.styleSheets` returns a `StyleSheetList` - a list of stylesheets and not a specific stylesheet, while `insertRule` is a method of `CSSStyleSheet`. in order to use this method you will have to select a specific stylesheet from the list.

take a look at the [second example here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule). they created a new stylesheet using `document.createElement`, added it to the head, and then inserted new rules to this stylesheet. something like this:

```
var styleElem = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(styleElem);
styleElem.sheet.insertRule( ... );
```

Checking for existing rules is more difficult because you will have to iterate over each sheet and rule to find out if there is already a rule that matches the new one.

Most of the time the browser will take the last rule it sees and override previous ones (unless it has the `!important` keyword).

Comment: Wouldn't that just change the style of the one page instead of the whole site? I'm using a basic.css for all the pages, thats why I thought it would be easiest to insert the rule in that stylesheet. When I get back the array of stylesheets how do I know witch index to use to select the stylesheet I want?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right...why don't you try using jQuery to modify the CSS of your Website or specific elements?

**css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});**

Example:

**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
    });
});
```

**